# What is a good way of visualising numeric query results?

Tags: data-visualization

Suppose that I have a query with $N$ questions each of which have $M$ numeric answer options. Thus, there are $N \times M$ possible answers available. I have a data set of answers to this query, and I wonder what would be an effective way of visualising them to see what kind of answers are typical. I was thinking some kind of a heat map, but any ideas would be appreciated.

**Example:**
$N = M = 10$, and possible answers in each question are integers in $[1, 10]$. Results presented in a table:

$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
&Q1&Q2&Q3&Q4&Q5&Q6&Q7&Q8&Q9&Q10\\
\hline
I1&1&2&1&1&1&5&2&1&1&10\\
I2&10&10&10&10&10&10&10&10&10&10\\
I3&10&10&10&10&10&10&10&10&10&10\\
I4&2&2&1&1&7&8&9&9&10&11\\
I5&1&1&1&2&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
I6&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1
\end{array}
 $$

So each column represents one question, and each row represents an interviewee and their answers. In this case, there were six interviewees.

Comment: Likely answers do depend on $M$ and $N$.  A concrete data example would help.

Comment: This question is too broad and speculative. Can you show some data/examples?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share any real data. In my problem, you could think of $N=M=10$ and answers being integers between 1 and 5.

Comment: You can invent a fake example with the same flavour.

Comment: @NickCox Added a fake example as a table.

Comment: > "What if I had thousands of interviewees?" That's why you make sure your question is a realistic description of the actual situation you face. We can only answer the question you write. You picked N = M = 10 creating a (false?) impression that you have data on the scale of 10x of pairs.

Comment: @dipetkov N = number of questions in the query; M = number of possible answers to one question

Comment: The question is quite unclear still.

Comment: Pardon me for repeating myself. But how are we supposed to know how many questions and possible answers there are? What are the actual numbers M and N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use heatmap, where you would show your data as a grid where each cell is colored by the numerical value. You could either use distinct colors, color range, or intensity of the colors to show different values. Distinct colors may make sense if there is no continuity between subsequent values, they are categorical.

[image]

([example source](https://towardsdatascience.com/heatmap-basics-with-pythons-seaborn-fb92ea280a6c))

If you cannot use colors, you can use a grayscale range, or put balls of sizes proportional to the numerical values inside the cells as in the example below. Beware however that people are rather bad of visually judging relative sizes of the objects.

[image]

Comment: Personally I think that the second option is a poor choice: Either you leave the numbers out and then one has to interpret areas and color saturation which is hard. Or you print the numbers next to the dot, which is basically a table, and doesn't look aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: The heatmap can be improved and made more interpretable by fixing the scale to range from 1 to 10 as these are the natural bounds on the values. (Not sure when the OP added this information in.)

Comment: So in my example, I would simply replace the numbers in the table with colors? What if I had thousands of interviewees?

Comment: @mathslover yes. If you had thousands of them, colors would likely be easier to digest than 1000s * M numbers.

Answer (score 2):

With this small a dataset, a multiple bar chart is possible. As the order of identifiers and indeed the order of questions may be arbitrary, sorting rows and columns according to level (e.g. means) may help to see structure.

[image]

[image]

Here I add a frame, so that it is earlier to see when answers are near 0 or near 10.

The problem of ordering rows and columns of such an array is often called *seriation*, especially in archaeology.